# Exception in Inflating Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm creating a menu and detail navigation activity. In which there will be two fragments i.e. one for display of the menu and one for display of details.
For display of the menu, I'm using a `ListView` and for details I have `TextView`.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hsports.practicefragments.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/menuItems"
        android:name="com.example.hsports.practicefragments.menuItemsclass"
        class="com.example.hsports.practicefragments.menuItemsclass"

        />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:name="com.example.hsports.practicefragments.detailsclass"
        class="com.example.hsports.practicefragments.detailsclass"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.hsports.practicefragments;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**displaymenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**displaydetails.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Osname"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Osversion"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**detailclass.java**

```
package com.example.hsports.practicefragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by I324671 on 9/28/2016.
 */
public class detailsclass extends Fragment {

    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.displaydetails,container,false);
        tv1=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Osname);
        tv2=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Osversion);

        return v;
    }

    public void change(String osname,String version)
    {
        tv1.setText(osname);
        tv1.setText(version);
    }
}
```

**menuItemsclass.java**

```
package com.example.hsports.practicefragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by I324671 on 9/28/2016.
 */
public class menuItemsclass extends ListFragment {

ListView lv;

    String androidOs[]={"IOS","Marshmallow","Gingerbread","OxygenOs","BADA"};
    String versionOs[]={"1","2","3","4","5"};

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.displaymenu,container);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,androidOs);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        detailsclass obj=(detailsclass)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
        obj.change(androidOs[position],versionOs[position]);
    }
}
```

The error which I'm getting is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.hsports.practicefragments, PID: 3014
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hsports.practicefragments/com.example.hsports.practicefragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
     at com.example.hsports.practicefragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
     at com.example.hsports.practicefragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
     at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
     at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:954)
     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1228)
     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2201)
     at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5546)
     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
     at com.example.hsports.practicefragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: I can help you share **build.gradle**

Comment: ListFragment -- [your view hierarchy *must* contain a ListView object with the id `@android:id/list`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html). So, you could just not use a ListFragment

Answer (score 0):

The issue is mentioned here:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id
>   attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class

So, in your `displaymenu.xml`, specify the the `id` attribute as:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    >

</ListView>
```